# Exception when serializing enum values with Flags attribute

Tags: protobuf-net

Is itpossible to serialize `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection` using protobuf-net? The following exception occur while trying to serialize:

> Only data-contract classes (and lists/arrays of such) can be processed (error processing SessionStateItemCollection)

What do I need to do to serialize this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with `[Flags]`, unless you are seeing something else...

protobuf-net serializes objects in accordance with the protobuf spec defined by google, which is a portable format that requires the receiever to know the layout of the specific data *in advance* - by which I mean that (unlike `BinaryFormatter`) it **doesn't** include anything to say "this object is a `MyCorp.Something.Customer` from `MyCorp.Something.dll`". This "don't store what the object *was*" approach is also common to json (`JavaScriptSerializer`), xml (`XmlSerializer`), `DataContractSerializer`, etc.

So why does this matter? It matters because session state is storing **arbitrary objects** that can't be predicted. Indeed, there is no guarantee (especially if the state has always been stored in memory) that the objects are even *remotely* serializable under *any* scheme.

But it depends on what your aim is; if you want to *implement a session-state provider*, then that should be possible - but you would just need to include this extra metadata in your provider, like I did when writing a [cache provider](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/01/distributed-caching-with-protobuf-net.html). So it would be:

- serialization:

  - encode the `GetType()` metadata in some way
  - use `Serialzier.NonGeneric` to encode the object (assuming it is serializable by protobuf-net)
- deserialization

  - decode the type metadata and resolve your `Type`
  - use `Serializer.NonGeneric` to decode the object

Another alternative approach would be to simply use `BinaryFormatter` which *handles the type metadata internally*, but hook `ISerializable` for your special types and forward that to protobuf-net. This allows your objects to be handled side-by-side with objects that aren't protobuf-net compatible, but get the enhanced serialization for your objects. A brief example of proxying `ISerializable` would be simply:

```
// these are the 2 methods used by ISerializable
protected YourType(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{ // ctor, used for deserialization
    Serializer.Merge(info, this);
}
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{ // used for serialization
    Serializer.Serialize(info, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am trying the same approach as you said let you know if i face any other problem. Thanks once again.